# Solve a simple packing combination with dependencies

Tags: python, algorithm, math, random, combinations

[image: A packing configuration of 7 boxes]

This is not a homework question, but something that came up from a project I am working on. The picture above is a packing configuration of a set of boxes, where A,B,C,D is on the first layer and E,F,G on the second layer. The question is that if the boxes are given in a random order, what is the probability that the boxes can be placed in the given configuration?

The only condition for the placement is all the boxes need to be placed from top down and cannot be moved once placed. Therefore no sliding under the existing box or floating placement is allowed, but it's okay to save room for the box on the same layer. For example, E can only be placed when A and B are already in place. If the handing order is AEB... then it cannot be placed in the specified configuration, if the handing sequence is ACBE... then E can be correctly placed.

A more formulated description is to translate the packing configuration to a set of dependencies, or prerequisites. ABCD on the first layer has 0 dependencies, while dependencies of E are {A and B}, F are {B and C}, and G are {C and D}, the corresponding dependencies must happen before E or F or G happens. Also while it doesn't apply to this problem, in some problem the dependencies could also be of a "or" relationship instead of "and".

I wonder what are the general deterministic algorithms to solve this, or this class of problem? A way I could think of is generating A,B,C,D,E,F,G in random order for 10,000 times and for each order check if the corresponding prerequisites have happened when each element is called. This naive idea, however, is time consuming and cannot produce the exact probability(I believe the answer to this problem is ~1/18 based on this naive algorithm I implemented).

And advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what have you  tried?

Comment: @user4343502 I mentioned my current thought in the last paragraph

Comment: This is a cool problem but might be better suited for [math.se]

Comment: Hi @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree this is a math problem, although I am more curious about if there already exists a general algorithm for solving this kind of problem. This will become quite messy mathematically once the problem scales up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 E F G
A B C D
```

In this particular instance you posted, there are two ways each to arrange `ABE` and `CDG`, and the two groups can be interleaved any which way.

```
4 * (3 + 4 - 1) choose 3 = 80
```

Now we're left with placing `F` anywhere after `B` and `C`. Analyzing the distribution of the index of `F`, we get:

```
{2: 12, 3: 36, 4: 64, 5: 80, 6: 80}
```

Trying to come up for a formula for this particular set of dependencies is, as you suggest, "messy." In this case, I might have generated the interleaving first two pyramids and then count the ways to place `F` in each one since a combinatoric solution seems just as complicated.

To scale a problem like this generally, one could run a search through the graph as well as exploit symmetries. In this case starting with `A` would be akin to starting with `D`; `B` with `C`.

Python example:

```py
nodes = {
  'A': {
    'neighbours': ['B','C','D','E','F','G'], 'dependency': set()},
  'B': {
    'neighbours': ['A','C','D','E','F','G'], 'dependency': set()},
  'C': {
    'neighbours': ['A','B','D','E','F','G'], 'dependency': set()},
  'D': {
    'neighbours': ['A','B','C','E','F','G'], 'dependency': set()},
  'E': {
    'neighbours': ['C','D','F','G'], 'dependency': set(['A','B'])},
  'F': {
    'neighbours': ['A','D','E','G'], 'dependency': set(['B','C'])},
  'G': {
    'neighbours': ['A','B','E','F'], 'dependency': set(['C','D'])}
}

def f(key, visited):
  if len(visited) + 1 == len(nodes):
    return 1

  if nodes[key]['dependency'] and not nodes[key]['dependency'].issubset(visited):
    return 0

  result = 0

  for neighbour in nodes[key]['neighbours']:
    if neighbour not in visited:
      _visited = visited.copy()
      _visited.add(key)
      result += f(neighbour, _visited)

  return result

print 2 * f('A', set()) + 2 * f('B', set()) # 272

# Probability = 272 / 7! = 17 / 315 = 0.05396825396825397
```

Comment: This is a well thought out answer. I am especially impressed that you calculated the probability by hand... The general algorithm can be further speed up though, despite already being much faster than going though all permutations. For example, if none of the node has dependencies ( e.g. all boxes on the same layer), the probability should be 1 with no further computation needed, while using this algorithm all graphs need to be fully explored before returning 1. Do you have any insights to further optimize this algorithm, probably by pre-grouping the nodes based on their dependencies?

Comment: @Susie interesting question about how to further optimise. It seems to me that each case might offer different optimisation clues so it's hard to generalize. Intuitively, it seems that the more intricate the dependencies are, the lower the probability and the more likely it will be fast enough to traverse the graph.

Comment: I got some cues to further optimize the problem from your answer, which is to resolve the dependency graph and divide the cubes in groups that are independent of the existence of others. The 7 blocks in this specific case cannot be resolved like that, but if F doesn't exist, the grouping can be done. From your experience, can you suggest some fast method to divide the cubes into such independent groups?

Comment: @Susie good question. Maybe post it to get more varied feedback?

Comment: Good suggestion, will be doing that!

Comment: I have posted a new question as in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126232/fastest-way-of-counting-all-possibilities-of-going-through-a-dependency-graph , I have never referenced a previous post on this site and couldn't reference your name correctly, please suggest modifications to the new post! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a counting approach.  There are two types of boxes: small (`S`) and large (`L`).  There are `N` different permutations of boxes, and each of them correlates with a bit string (ex: `ABCDEFG` is `SSSSLLL` or `0000111`).

You can find the number of permutations where the number of smalls up to and including some `L` letter is strictly greater than the number of larges.

For example, in `SSLSSLL`, when you reach the first `L`, there are two `S`'s and one `L` up to that point (so `S` > `L`), and for the last two, the number of `S`'s is greater than the number of `L`'s.

Answer (score 0):

There is 5040 (7!) possible permutations. The number of permutations is small enough in order to implement a script which checks for every permutation if it's a "valid" permutation (ie: can reach given configuration). And you can deduce the probability: valid_permutations/all_permutations

Now, the problem becomes how do i check if a permutation is valid? If i understand correctly a permutation is valid if and only if:

- E is after A and B
- F is after B and C
- G is after C and D

So the code becomes (after transforming A...B in 0..6):

```
valids = 0
range7 = range(7)
for perm in itertools.permutations(range7):
    indexes = [perm.index(x) for x in range7]
    if (indexes[4] < indexes[0] or indexes[4] < indexes[1]):
        continue
    if (indexes[5] < indexes[1] or indexes[5] < indexes[2]):
        continue
    if (indexes[6] < indexes[2] or indexes[6] < indexes[3]):
        continue
    valids += 1
print(valids / 5040.)
# 5,39 %!
```

Comment: This is absolutely correct and easy to understand, it is slower(~30 times slower for this specific case )than the accepted answer but not too slow for small problems like this one.