# Number of ways to go through a partially ordered set

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, combinations, poset

This is built upon a previous question [Solve a simple packing combination with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948256/solve-a-simple-packing-combination-with-dependencies), although there is no need to check out that question to understand this one.

This question asks about the fastest ways to count the number of linear extensions of a partially ordered set.

Such an partially ordered list can be visualized as the feasibility of a packing configuration, given arbitrary ordering of the objects. The question is than equivalent to what are the possible ordering of all the blocks handed to you for you to achieve the shown packing configuration, if the blocks cannot be moved once placed?

[image]

In this example, all blocks ABCDEFG need to be laid down,dependencies for A,B,C,D: set{}, E: set{A,B},F: set{B,C} G: set{C,D}.

You can get all possibilities of completing the partially ordered set by checking all permutations of 7 blocks and count the number that meets the dependencies. A faster alternative is provided by גלעד ברקן in the previous post who used a graph structure that terminate further search into a branch if the dependencies are not met in nodes already explored.

```
nodes = {
  'A': {
    'neighbours': ['B','C','D','E','F','G'], 'dependency': set()},
  'B': {
    'neighbours': ['A','C','D','E','F','G'], 'dependency': set()},
  'C': {
    'neighbours': ['A','B','D','E','F','G'], 'dependency': set()},
  'D': {
    'neighbours': ['A','B','C','E','F','G'], 'dependency': set()},
  'E': {
    'neighbours': ['C','D','F','G'], 'dependency': set(['A','B'])},
  'F': {
    'neighbours': ['A','D','E','G'], 'dependency': set(['B','C'])},
  'G': {
    'neighbours': ['A','D','E','G'], 'dependency': set(['C','D'])},

}

def f(key, visited):
  if len(visited) + 1 == len(nodes):
    return 1

  if nodes[key]['dependency'] and not nodes[key]['dependency'].issubset(visited):
    return 0

  result = 0

  for neighbour in nodes[key]['neighbours']:
    if neighbour not in visited:
      _visited = visited.copy()
      _visited.add(key)
      result += f(neighbour, _visited)

  return result

print 2 * f('A', set()) + 2 * f('B', set()) # exploiting symmetry
```

My question is that if there is any way to further optimize upon גלעד ברקן's algorithm without losing generality? I can probably make it faster if the dependencies are scarce and the list can be further broken down into independent sub-lists but that's not the case for this particular example.

Comment: What have you tried in order to cluster independent groups? How would you do it conceptually without a computer?

Comment: This sounds like counting the number of linear extensions of a partially ordered set, which in general is #P-hard. Partitioning the instance in the manner that you describe is related to finding a partial series-parallel decomposition. Are all of the instances geometric like the ones above? That might pave the way for a better algorithm.

Comment: @גלעדברקן, I think conceptually, this is to divide all your nodes into max number of groups while satisfy the condition that if the dependencies of any member of one group is not empty, the dependencies should be within it's own group.

Comment: @גלעדברקן, to write an algorithm, I personally would iterate through all nodes, initialize a new group if the node have no dependencies or if the dependencies were not in the existing group. If the dependencies exist in the previous group(s), then add this node and its dependencies in the existing group, And if dependencies of the node exist in several existing groups, combine those groups into one.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, you are right! I googled and this is the problem of linear extension of a poset, although I didn't find much resource on the algorithmic side of the problem either. I guess now the question narrows down to if an algorithm faster than the one in the post can be written to solve the # decomposition in the second packing configuration with ABCDEFG.